# Fat Jar to Implement a Language Server

Tags: dockerfile, xtext, eclipse-che, shadowjar, fatjar

I am trying to build a language server to be implemented as a sidecar for eclipse che. I built a fat jar from a xtext language server that I've created. Can I use this fat jar to implement my language server in a dockerfile in order to run my language server as a container?

I wrote a Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM barais/eclipse-xtend
ADD build/libs/dsl-language-server-ls.jar dsl-language-server-ls.jar
RUN sudo apt-get install socat
CMD socat TCP4-LISTEN:4417,reuseaddr,fork EXEC:"mydsl"
```

"dsl-language-server-ls.jar" is the jar file made by building my project (i.e, the LS). My question is, can I run my language server by including the .jar file as in the above dockerfile? It actually worked in eclipse che, but I still get a broken pipe error, and a timeout error which makes me doubt my approach.

[Language Server Initialization Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY4mO.png)

This is the error I'm getting.

Comment: Why do you want to run the server in a container? Is it possible you read the term server in language server wrong. The last time I worked with Che you downloaded and started the lsp hat as part of the ws agent

Comment: To implement a sidecar, is it not required to run the server in parallel? I thought that is what is mentioned in the Che document.https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/language-servers.html#ls-sidecars

Comment: Yes that is an alternate approach

Comment: But this still does not explain what your problem is

Comment: I updated my question. I guess you can get a rough idea now.

Comment: Have no idea on that. Does the error happen on client or on server side

Comment: I improved my question again by including the error. Is it really possible to run a Xtext-based language server as a sidecar in eclipse. Is my approach correct? I'm quite new to these technologies. I would highly appreciate any help. The error happens in server side upto my knowledge.

Comment: Do you expose the ports correctly. Is the server started and reachable. Is everything you need in the image eg Java

Comment: Is the startup script and the structure copied correctly to the image ?

Comment: I only included in the dockerfile what I have mentioned above in my question. I can run the image through the command line, yet when I try to access the port I get an error : 
2018/10/05 03:56:21 socat[11] E execvp("mydsl", "mydsl"): No such file or directory

2018/10/05 03:56:21 socat[12] E execvp("mydsl", "mydsl"): No such file or directory

2018/10/05 03:56:21 socat[9] E write(3, 0x1ab45c0, 406): Broken pipe

Comment: What is meant by "socat[12] E execvp("mydsl", "mydsl"): No such file or directory"? I tried making various changes to "fork EXEC:"mydsl"", yet the error exists.

Comment: There is no startup script found in your image

Comment: You package the jar and startup script wrongly to your image

Comment: You were right. My EXEC was wrong. I should change the EXEC command as: EXEC:"java -jar dsl-language-server-ls.jar". I had to install jdk as well.

Comment: Thanks for the support and patience! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will only work if you package your docker image correctly

- make sure you include java 8
- make sure that your either include not only the jar but the startupscripts from the build directory too
- or you simply call `java -jar yourjar.jar` instead of the `mydsl` startup script

Comment: I have 4 directories within the build directory: classes, libs, resources, temp. The .jar is in the libs directory. I cannot seem to find a startup script in any of these directories. What file extension do you think a startup script may carry? Or should I create one?

Comment: Even though my grammar rules are applied correctly when I create a file that uses my language server, I get a warning saying "[WARN ] [o.e.l.j.s.GenericEndpoint 137] -Unsupported notifiction method: textDocument/semanticHighlighting". Do you think this is because I haven't included the startup script? The keywords do not get highlighted in my files as said in the warning.

Comment: Make sure xtext version and api Version in the Client match

Comment: Is it the build.gradle file in the .ide directory you meant by startup script?

Comment: and no the startupscript is not the cause. it is your client. it uses too old language client. which client do you use?

Comment: I'm implementing this language server to Eclipse Che. I created the language server using Eclipse Photon.

Comment: hmmm so it might be better you use photon xtext (214) as well

Comment: I installed the new release of Xtext, still I get the same error after redoing the same procedure.

Comment: In the build.gradle of the parent directory, I have the following as the xtext version:
ext.xtextVersion = '2.16.0-SNAPSHOT'

Comment: no. i  mean  CLIENT side. which lsp4j version does your che use. if its old you should use xtext 2.14

Comment: I changed the Xtext version to 2.14 as you suggested. It must have worked since I'm no longer getting the error. However, still the text doesn't get highlighted.

Comment: There is no server side highlight in. Xtext 214

Comment: Could you kindly tell me how I can include syntax highlighting in Xtext 2.14? If it not possible, then how do I add syntax highlighting?

Comment: If client does not support it or you do use older Xtext this is usually done via textmate grammars on the client side so you should look how to make client side highlighting in che or when che will update and support server side highlighting